# Run 2 uWSGI on the same server with Nginx

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi

Is it possible to run two separate uWSGI process on the same server with Nginx serving up both sets of static files?

So far, this setup appears to work sometimes, but requests are failing sometimes....

**nginx.conf**:

```
http {
    upstream deploy {
        server 127.0.0.1:8002;
    }

    server {
        # nginx config - deploy
    }

    upstream staging {
        server 127.0.0.1:8001;
    }

    server {
        # nginx config - staging
    }
}
```

I do have on both uWSGI.ini files `master=True`.  Here's what they both look like:

**uwsgi.ini**

```
[uwsgi]

home = /home/bsdev/.virtualenvs/bs_py34/
env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myproject.settings.persistent

socket = 127.0.0.1:8003
chmod-socket = 666
uid = bsdev
gid = bsdev
master = true
enable-threads = true
processes = 4

chdir = /www/django/releases/persistent/bsrs/bsrs-django/myproject
module = myproject.wsgi:application
pidfile = /tmp/myproject-master-persistent.pid
harakiri = 10
max-requests = 5000
logdate = true
vacuum = true

daemonize = /var/log/uwsgi/myproject-persistent.log
logdate = true
```

Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Does anyone have a working configuration?

It seems like having them both as master, or if the same uwsgi process is serving both, that requests are getting dropped....

Thanks in advance.

Stack:

- Nginx
- uwsgi
- Django 1.8

Comment: Both of them can work, I think. But you need to set different path for location settings. And you also need to know that session_id is sharing with 2 uwsgi processes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To hold two and more separate projects, l'd recommend the following:

1. Install separate uWSGI for each project in its virtualenv
2. Create separate virtual servers in nginx/sites-available for each project, pointing at its own uWSGI